# i need to ask the user to enter his date of birth and check if it is in the correct form using javascript. my code is not working

Tags: javascript

I need the user to enter his date of birth using prompt and the date of birth should be in this format dd/mm/year. My code looks like this: how can i fix it? i just need the year part. i already figured out the month and day.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var birth=prompt("enter your date of birth","");
birth=birth.search(/^\d{2} \\ \d{2} \\ \d{4}$/ );
if(birth==-1)
{
  alert("the date should not be in this form \n");

}
else
alert("OK");

</script>
```

Comment: This is wrong on several levels. Don't reinvent the wheel; search for a [javascript date picker](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+picker) instead.

Comment: `birth=birth.search(/^(\d{2})[\ ]+(\d{2})[\ ]+(\d{4})$/ );`

Comment: Backslash does not require shielding. `\/` - only need to escape the slash.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for the format `dd \ mm \ yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy`

Replace `\\` with `\/` and remove all the spaces from your regexp.

Comment: @user3057109: I think he means `\/`; forward slashes need to be escaped in JavaScript regular expression literals.